# question about line bundle on projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a projective variety. Suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is a basepoint free globally generated line bundle so we get a map $\pi:X\to \mathbb{P}^N$ induced by $\mathcal{L}$.

Let $R_n=H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes{n}})$ and $R=\oplus_{n=0}^{\infty}R_n$. I vaguely remember that $\overline{\pi(X)}\cong \text{Proj} (R)$ (the grading is by natrual number) Is it true? In particular, when $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample,do we have $X\cong Proj(R)$?
Thank you!

Comment: What is $\overline{\pi(X)}$?

Comment: @Mohan: I guess it's the closure of the image under $\pi$ of $X$.  In this case, since $X$ was assumed projective, I guess it's actually just the image $\pi(X)$.

Comment: @Mohan bar(pi(X)) is closure of the image. Now I realize that it is just pi(X).

Comment: @tracing Yes you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For very ample, this is true and if not, in general it is false. Just as an example, take a degree 2 line bundle $L$ on an elliptic curve $X$. Then $N=1$ in your notation, so $\pi(X)=\mathbb{P}^1$. But, $\mathrm{Proj}\, R$ is just $X$, since $L$ is ample.

Comment: Thank you! is this result stated in Hartshorne?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that since you can always Veronese, you can also just take $\mathcal{L}$ to be ample.

Comment: Okay I see. If L is ample, then Proj R is always isomorphic to X.